# Dúvida Básica Relacionamento

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Boa noite pessoal, desculpe a pergunta, esse é o primeiro banco de dados que estou criando, então... Tenho essas 3 tabelas relacionadas, a minha dúvida é se devo manter as Tabelas Cliente e Funcionário fracas ou deixar endereço como a entidade fraca.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual resolve o modelo de negocios de forma mais simples ? Cliente até faz sentido ter mais de um endereço , mas funcionário ...

Comment: Pense o seguinte: endereço pode existir independente da existência de um funcionário ou de um cliente? Se qualquer endereço sempre estará associado a um dos dois então será uma entidade fraca.

Comment: Isso tudo depende da maneira como você deseja estabelecer a estrutura do sistema, mas pensa comigo. A entidade `endereço` **depende** de alguém para existir? Se sua resposta for sim, mantenha ela como entidade fraca. Caso contrário, aconselho remodelar seu sistema.